# Any way to read entity (schema) from revit document in Viewer?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

In the Revit project, a  [schema](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017.1/e90c01ab-3d2f-2f46-3e88-8297e686dc80.htm) is attached to the [Document.ProjectInformation](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017.1/4db36834-e324-b199-7a5a-e3218e95da37.htm) field. How can I get it in the viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Revit extensible storage data and schema is completely lost in the Forge viewer.

Remember that the Forge viewer is completely generic, supporting all CAD formats, and strongly optimised for performance.

Therefore, it cannot maintain any purely internal Revit or BIM specific data.

Furthermore, the extensible storage data is potentially confidential to an individual Revit add-in.

All data in the viewer is public for all to see.

Therefore, all extensible storage data *must* be removed in the Forge viewer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But is there really no way to transfer custom data from Revit to the Viewer?

Comment: there are millions of ways to transfer data from Revit to the Forge viewer. you can even transfer data back from the viewer to Revit. you can even do it live, in realtime. check out my samples on connecting desktop and cloud exemplified by the Revit BIM and various web services, listed in the [FireRatingCloud documentation](https://github.com/jeremytammik/FireRatingCloud).

Comment: Another nice sample demonstrating this is [RvtMetaProp](https://github.com/jeremytammik/rvtmetaprop).

Comment: Also check out my recent blog post on [Before Getting Started with Design Automation](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/03/before-getting-started-with-design-automation.html)